# To-do list and time-auditing software

Tags: productivity, to-do, time-management

I saw a couple other topics like this but i believe my requirements are a little different.

NEED:

---

I'm working on alot of odd jobs for several people and need to keep precise track of the time i spend doing each task. So at the very least i need something with a START button, a label, and a STOP button that would give me some kind of output like this:

```
Label:       Start time:    Time spent:
Research A   11:56AM        12:23AM
```

This much i could accomplish with any text editor/google doc spreadsheet, but:

Also, if I could somehow integrate this with a to-do list where i could build, and easily modify the todo list (ideally as easily as I would go about modifying this post) then have a "start/total time spent on task" element for each todo bullet, that would be ideal. The todo need to support subcategories.

WANT:

---

If this was web-based, that would be better, I can host it myself if need be, but I dont want a complicated UI.

Searching/sorting on the list(by task or by label) would be nice. If I could

If i could access it from a droid that would be ideal, but not necessary.

The todo can be accomplished by a wiki software, but id need a plugin for the rest i believe. If theres something like that, I could use it too, I can throw up a VM with apache and whatever I need if that would save me from having to write this myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an OS in mind?

Comment: Well, ideally web based so i could access it from droid, various *nix, and windows. but if I had to pick one, lets say Linux, debian or redhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you may have had trouble googling this is because it is more commonly known as time-tracking software.

Probably the best one IMO is [Nozbe](http://www.nozbe.com/index) which is part time tracking, part GTD system. Which, knowing how finicky GTD is, is insanely powerful.

And if that one doesn't work for you, I'll start you on your new quest with this [Lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5362829/five-best-time+tracking-applications).

Comment: The nozbe one looks great for to-do but I need more time tracking. However, the article has atleast 2 that looks very promising. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have some emphasis on managing your ToDo tasks, you might like to look at [Mark Forster's DWM methodology](http://www.markforster.net/blog/2010/2/1/dit2-af5-who-cares-what-its-called-this-is-what-im-working-o.html) as implemented in [an Excel spreadsheet](http://www.markforster.net/forum/post/1168638) by Walter. The spreadsheet contains description, expires, category, created, entered, start-time, end-time, invested-time; with macros to manage creating/timetracking the tasks.